# angular $http request from 80 port to another port

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, cors, cross-domain

I am trying to hit a node api with port 3000 on local server from a angular 1 project using $http method but I am getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/login. Request header
>   field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

I also added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` in node js as :

```
req.on('end', function() {
    req.rawBody = req.rawBody.toString('utf8');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    next();
});
```

And my angular code is :

```
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // 'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            },
            data: { username: username, password: password },
            json: true
        };

        $http(req).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response){
            console.log("Error : ");
            console.log(response);
        });
```

But still I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the preflight response as specified.
So you need to handle the OPTIONS method :

```
req.on('end', function() {
    req.rawBody = req.rawBody.toString('utf8');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);


    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        return res.status(200).end();
    }

    return next();
});
```

This is due to the way browsers handle cross-origin request. An OPTIONS request (preflight) is sent before your POST to get allowed origins, headers and methods.